# Did something change in the announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges

I earned the announcer badge three times at once last night. Previous time I got it was over 1.5 year ago, and I earned those new badges on quite old questions, and I did not share a link recently (I cannot even remember I share them...). As far as I remember was the bronze level always at 25 unique IP addresses. Did something change on the StackExchange-side, or was there some serial clicker lurking through old forum posts of me?

[image: SCreenshot of all my awards of the Announcer badge]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bug in calculating the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges for answers was fixed. [This main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339664/missing-publicist-badge/340289#340289) has the details.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That explains it indeed :)